# changing property of build-in webparts when web creates

Tags: web-part, list, sharepoint-enterprise

I have created a web template based on teamsite (removed wiki feature). I have added a task list and a members webpart on the onet.xml file. I want to change the default view on the task list and displaytype of the webpart programmatically so that when you crate a website of this template they are changed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: how about using site definition :)

Comment: if you go through onet.xml, you can add a webpart and setup its properties using XSLT

Comment: Yes, I have used xslt for example I added this <DisplayType>WebMemberGroup</DisplayType> to change DisplayType but it does not work.